# TCP Incoming packet logger

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp

I can't find any information about making a tcp/ip packet logger in a book. can someone point me in right direction or a book reference would be helpful.

Comment: See something similar to Wireshark.

Comment: What level are you trying to log at? IP, TCP or the application layer? You'll probably need to use a low-level library like Pcap.

Comment: @ Ak I think thats what I needed. You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply need a program to log tcp packets, have a look at Wireshark. If you actually want to write your own logger, you can use the [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) library. It is implemented in C and there are lots of tutorials / examples on the website. If you working in windows, you should have a look at [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/). [Here](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) is a nice easy tutorial for libpcap.